# Problems compiling in C, while included doesnt detect a struct

Tags: c

i´m trying to compile 3 files in C. One is `main.c`, where i declare the variables, another is `cuenta.h` and the other is cliente.h. `cuenta.h` has a struct used in another struct in `cliente.h`, but this error appears. How can I solve this? Thanks!

> cliente.h

```
#ifndef PACABANK_CLIENTE_H
#define PACABANK_CLIENTE_H

#include "cuenta.h"
#include "fecha.h"

typedef struct {
    char *dni;
    char *titular;
    Tarjeta tarjeta;
}InfoCliente;
```

> cuenta.h

```
#ifndef PACABANK_CUENTA_H
#define PACABANK_CUENTA_H

#include "cliente.h"
#include "fecha.h"

typedef struct
{
    int numero_tarjeta;
    char *iban;
    Fecha caducidad;
    char *nombre_titular;
    int cvv;
    char *tipo; //mastercard, visa, american express.....
    float limite;
}Tarjeta;
```

> The error

```
In file included from cuenta.h:7:0,
                 from cuenta.c:5:
cliente.h:14:5: error: unknown type name 'Tarjeta'
     Tarjeta tarjeta;
```

Comment: It’s not necessary to include “client.h” in cuenta.h

Comment: You have a cross include, remove the include of cliente.h in cuenta.h

Comment: To expand on @Hitokiri comment. By including `cliente.h` into `cuenta.h` it causes the `InfoCliente` definition to appear before the  `Tarjeta` definition. You haven't shown the whole file so it is not clear whether `curenta.h` really needs anything from `cliente.h`. If not, simply remove the `#include cliente.h`

Comment: Unrelated, but important: Use header guards!